# Is there a way to call a private Class method from an instance in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, scope, visibility, class-method, access-specifier

Other than `self.class.send :method, args...`, of course.  I'd like to make a rather complex method available at both the class and instance level without duplicating the code.

---

**UPDATE:**

@Jonathan Branam: that was my assumption, but I wanted to make sure nobody else had found a way around.  Visibility in Ruby is very different from that in Java.  You're also quite right that `private` doesn't work on class methods, though this will declare a private class method:

```
class Foo
  class <<self
    private
    def bar
      puts 'bar'
    end
  end
end

Foo.bar
# => NoMethodError: private method 'bar' called for Foo:Class
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a code snippet to go along with the question. Using "private" in a class definition does not apply to class methods. You need to use "private_class_method" as in the following example.

```
class Foo
  def self.private_bar
    # Complex logic goes here
    puts "hi"
  end
  private_class_method :private_bar
  class <<self
    private
    def another_private_bar
      puts "bar"
    end
  end
  public
  def instance_bar
    self.class.private_bar
  end
  def instance_bar2
    self.class.another_private_bar
  end
end

f=Foo.new
f=instance_bar # NoMethodError: private method `private_bar' called for Foo:Class
f=instance_bar2 # NoMethodError: private method `another_private_bar' called for Foo:Class
```

I don't see a way to get around this. The documentation says that you cannot specify the receive of a private method. Also you can only access a private method from the same instance. The class Foo is a different object than a given instance of Foo.

Don't take my answer as final. I'm certainly not an expert, but I wanted to provide a code snippet so that others who attempt to answer will have properly private class methods.

Comment: This would be good as a part of the question, not the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Let me contribute to this list of more or less strange solutions and non-solutions:

```rb
puts RUBY_VERSION # => 2.1.2

class C
  class << self
    private def foo
      'Je suis foo'
    end
  end

  private define_method :foo, &method(:foo)

  def bar
    foo
  end
end

puts C.new.bar # => Je suis foo
puts C.new.foo # => NoMethodError
```

Comment: As the original post requests, it should *call* the class method. This isn't good as it's copying the method into the class's set of instance methods.  If you, for example, monkey patch the class method C::foo, you'd suddenly have mismatching behavior between the class level ::foo and instance level #foo.

Comment: @ChadM, nobody said monkey patching made sense, even less of a private method. If you monkey patch, you must know what you're doing and take the inconveniences. One doesn't optimize code for future monkey patching.

Comment: @akostadinov, yes, I would advise me of 2016 similar sentiments and would change my decision if Stackoverflow would allow it.

Comment: @akostadinov That said, I still wouldn't use this method. Still better to just use `send` and actually call the original code than duplicate it.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays you don't need the helper methods anymore. You can simply inline them with your method definition. This should feel very familiar to the Java folks:

```
class MyClass

  private_class_method def self.my_private_method
    puts "private class method"
  end

  private def my_private_method
    puts "private instance method"
  end

end
```

And no, you cannot call a private class method from an instance method. However, you could instead implement the the **private** class method as **public** class method in a **private** nested class instead, using the `private_constant` helper method. See [this blogpost](https://blog.arkency.com/2016/02/private-classes-in-ruby/) for more detail.

Comment: Since which ruby version exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If your method is merely a [utility function](https://github.com/kevinrutherford/reek/wiki/utility-function) (that is, it doesn't rely on any instance variables), you could put the method into a module and `include` and `extend` the class so that it's available as both a private class method and a private instance method.

Comment: I always confuse these too. Example would be helpful.

Comment: Also would be good to be sure that the methods that you borrowed are private on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to play with "real" private class methods.

```
class Foo
  def self.private_bar
    # Complex logic goes here
    puts "hi"
  end
  private_class_method :private_bar
  class <<self
    private
    def another_private_bar
      puts "bar"
    end
  end
  public
  def instance_bar
    self.class.private_bar
  end
  def instance_bar2
    self.class.another_private_bar
  end
  def calling_private_method
    Foo.send :another_private_bar
    self.class.send :private_bar
  end
end
f=Foo.new
f.send :calling_private_method 
 # "bar"
 # "hi"
Foo.send :another_private_bar
# "bar"
```

cheers

Comment: Getting an error for the first example: `1.9.3p327 :078 > f=Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x0000000293baa0> 
1.9.3p327 :079 > f.class.send :calling_private_method 
NoMethodError: undefined method \`calling_private_method' for Foo:Class
        from (irb):79
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb:16:in \`<main>'`

Comment: Yeah, this does not work (or perhaps no longer works).

Comment: @metakungfu the part I (still) take issue with is calling a private class method from any instance method. From within the instance method, `self.class.some_private_method` will throw an error. It bothers me that, unless we use reflection, private class methods can only be used by other class methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most "native vanilla Ruby" way:

```
class Foo
  module PrivateStatic # like Java
    private def foo
      'foo'
    end
  end
  extend PrivateStatic
  include PrivateStatic

  def self.static_public_call
    "static public #{foo}"
  end

  def public_call
    "instance public #{foo}"
  end
end

Foo.static_public_call # 'static public foo'
Foo.new.public_call # 'instance public foo'
Foo.foo # NoMethodError: private method `foo' called for Foo:Class
Foo.new.foo # NoMethodError: private method `foo' called for #<Foo:0x00007fa154d13f10>
```

With some Ruby metaprogramming, you could even make it look like:

```
class Foo
  def self.foo
    'foo'
  end

  extend PrivateStatic
  private_static :foo
end
```

Ruby's metaprogramming is quite powerful, so you could technically implement any scoping rules you might want. That being said, I'd still prefer the clarity and [minimal surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) of the first variant.

Comment: Wouldn't this method have a direct access to instance attributes? I.e. it ruins the purpose of a wish to define it outside of the instance class.

Answer (score 0):

The prior examples (no longer?) work.  You cannot call the private class method directly; even from within the same class.  Instead, you need to use `send`.

```
class Foo
  def self.a_method
    puts "uses #{private_method} from class method"
  end

  def a_method
    # normally this would be done with an alias or include+extend a module or calling self.class.a_method
    puts "uses #{private_method} from instance method"
  end

  class << self
    private

    def private_method
      "private class method"
    end
  end

  private

  def private_method
    self.class.send(:private_method)
  end
end

Foo.a_method => 'uses private class method from class method'
Foo.new.a_method => 'uses private class method from instance method'
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, don't you just need something like this:

```
class Foo
    private
    def Foo.bar
        # Complex logic goes here
        puts "hi"
    end

    public
    def bar
        Foo.bar
    end
end
```

Of course you could change the second definition to use your self.class.send approach if you wanted to avoid hardcoding the class name...